# tf.estimator wants label_data and batch_size for prediction Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, predict, tensor

I have created a network using high level tf APIs such as tf.estimator.

Training and evaluating work fine and produce an output. However when predicting on new data, `get_inputs()` requires `label_data` and `batch_size`.

The error is: `TypeError: get_inputs() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'label_data' and 'batch_size'`

How can I resolve this so I can make a prediction?

Here is my code:

```
predictTest = [0.34, 0.65, 0.88]
```

predictTest is just a test and won't be my real prediction data.

get_inputs(), this is where the error is thrown.

```
def get_inputs(feature_data, label_data, batch_size, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (feature_data, label_data))

    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(feature_data))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels
```

Prediction inputs:

```
def predict_input_fn():
    return get_inputs(
    predictTest,
    n_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False
    )
```

Predicting:

```
predict = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
print("Prediction: {}".format(list(predict)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that I must create a new `get_inputs()` function for the prediction.

If I use the `get_inputs()` that train and evaluate use, it is expecting data it won't get.

`get_inputs`:

```
def get_inputs(feature_data, label_data, batch_size, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( #from_tensor_slices
        (feature_data, label_data))

    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(feature_data))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels
```

Make a new function called pred_get_inputs that doesn't require `label_data` or `batch_size`:

```
def get_pred_inputs(feature_data,n_epochs=None, shuffle=False):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( #from_tensor_slices
        (feature_data))

    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(feature_data))
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)
    features = dataset
    return features
```

Answer (score 0):

The testing of any model has two types. 
1) you want accuracy, recall etc. you need to provide a label for the test data. if you don't provide label it will give you an error.
2) you just want to test your model without calculating the accuracy than you don't need a label but here the prediction will be different.

Comment: I'm already testing the accuracy, The prediction says it needs label_data and batch_size

Comment: Yes. Testing accuracy needs to labeled. this how the accuracy has been measured. the model will predict and then compare with the original label. so label your data (testing data).